# passing parameters to the java program while running it through php

Tags: php

i wanted to pass parameters to the java program when i run it through php script 
could anyone tell me how to do that

Comment: can you show, how you run java program?

Answer (score 2):

**If you mean Java Applets:**

You can define parameters in the *parameter* element of the *applet* tag: `<param name="paramStr" value="someString"/>`

To get the value in Java, use the [getParameter()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)) method: `getParameter("paramStr");`

There is a good tutorial on Java Applets at Oracle's [The Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/param.html) site.

**If you want to use PHP's `exec()` function**:

You can pass arguments in `exec`'s command string:

```
exec("java -jar example.jar arg1 arg2");
```

Then in your main class you can use the arguments as if you run the program manually:

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass complete objects to Java via JSON. See [JSON](http://www.json.org/) for a brief description of the format and libraries that can serialize and deserialize objects formatted with JSON.